# How would I change this code to show if it is 'up', 'down' or 'same' as the previous number?

Tags: python

I have written some code that shows whether an inputted number is higher, lower or the same as a first inputted number. How would I change this code to show whether the inputted number is higher/lower/same as the previously inputted number, not just the first number.

```py
answers = ""
print("Enter the first number: ", end = "")
f = input()
first = int(f)
finished = False
while not finished:
    print("Enter the next number (0 to finish):  ", end = "")
    s = input()
    num = int(s)
    if num != 0:
        if num < first:
            answers += "Down "
        elif num > first:
            answers += "Up "
        elif num == first:
            answers += "Same "
    else:
        finished = True
        print(answers)
```

Comment: Why don't you compare against the previous number just as you compare against the first? What problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `first` you need to save the `prev` (previous) number, and update it every iteration:

```py
answers = ""
print("Enter the first number: ", end="")
f = input()
prev = int(f)
finished = False
while not finished:
    print("Enter the next number (0 to finish):  ", end="")
    s = input()
    num = int(s)
    if num != 0:
        if num < prev:
            answers += "Down "
        elif num > prev:
            answers += "Up "
        elif num == prev:
            answers += "Same "
        prev = num  ######## <=========== this is the line that updates prev to the current num
    else:
        finished = True
        print(answers)
```

example:

```
Enter the first number: 1
Enter the next number (0 to finish):  2
Enter the next number (0 to finish):  3
Enter the next number (0 to finish):  2
Enter the next number (0 to finish):  2
Enter the next number (0 to finish):  1
Enter the next number (0 to finish):  0
Up Up Down Same Down
```